# OS X 11.4 Xcode 7.3 Swift REPL Error

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm new to Swift and I using Swift REPL to do some code.
And hers's the error.

[image]

But at the end of this long error log it comes :"Welcome to Apple Swift version 2.2 (swiftlang-703.0.18.1 clang-703.0.29). Type :help for assistance."

Is there something wrong and how can I fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** - Check your `PATH` environment variable.

I had this same issue and was able to get through it.  In my case I had MAMP PRO installed and was using a modified `PATH` for it.  That turned out to be problematic for using the `swift` REPL.

I use Zsh as my default terminal shell, so in my `~/.zshrc` file (`~/.bashrc` is the equivalent for Bash) I had changed

```
export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:$PATH"
```

to

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin"
```

and restarted my terminal session.  The `swift` REPL was now starting up properly again.

I had not checked thoroughly if this adjustment adversely affected my MAMP PRO setup but a quick check suggested that this change was fine.

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me too. Not really know about ur problem but I solved mine by reinstalling the newest version of Xcode. That happened mostly because you did not update the new version of Mac which is required to run the newest Xcode which caused the terminal repl problem because the Xcode can not be run at the first place.